# How to read certain data from a file and display it?

Tags: c#, file-io

Suppose I have a file and it contains the following content:

```
Game Name: Candy Crush
Game Type: Match Three
Game Difficulty Rating: 8

Game Name: Maplestory
Game Type: RPG
Game Difficulty: 6

Game Name: Runescape
Game Type: RPG
Game Difficulty: 6

Game Name: GTA
Game Type: Video
Game Difficulty: 7
```

How do I post only RPG games on a message box? I would like to display all of the data for each RPG game listed.

I've tried this code just now but it seems to be displaying all of it.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = File.ReadAllText("Games.txt");
    var enter = Environment.NewLine;

    var gamestrings = games.Select(x => string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}", x.Name, x.Type, x.Difficulty));
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(enter + enter, gamestrings));

    var games = file.Split(new[] { enter + enter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Split(new[] { enter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(e => new { Name = e[0], Type = e[1], Difficulty = e[2] }).Where(x => x.Type.Contains("RPG"));
}
```

Giving me errors:

```
Cannot use local variable 'games' before it is declared

A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a     different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
```

Comment: I recommend that you carefully read [this post](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @HighCore What if I only tried reading the entire file instead?

Comment: then you need to post your current code in the question, and specify which parts of that code you're having trouble with, and what/how is not working and what is your expected result.

Comment: @HighCore I tried the one that can count how many RPGs are there but I was thinking of only displaying.

Comment: @puretppc: After your edit: You still have `File.ReadAllText("Games.txt")` in your program. Remove it alltogether.

Comment: string contents = File.ReadAllText("Games.txt"); change to string contents = "";

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I changed it but it still seems to give a blank.

Comment: @puretppc: So how does you program look like now?

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I made the edit. string contents = "";

Comment: @puretppc: I also see that you've changed the file name to `FriendsList.txt` instead of `Games.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `StreamReader` stuff, and leave this:

```
var file = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Games.txt");
```

*(Make sure you enter the correct file path in there!!)*

Second, since your data file is separated with two `Enter`s, let's take advantage of that. Let's split the string into parts divided by these 2 enters and then divide again each enter to have each Game's details into a single record, for that we will conveniently define this variable:

```
var enter = Environment.NewLine;
```

Third, **LINQ** to the Rescue!!

You can choose between the Lambda Syntax:

```
var games = file.Split(new[] {enter + enter}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split(new[] {enter}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .Select(e => new {Name = e[0], Type = e[1], Difficulty = e[2]})
                .Where(x => x.Type.Contains("RPG"));
```

Or the Query syntax:

```
var games = from g in file.Split(new[] {enter + enter}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            let gamestrings = g.Split(new[] {enter}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            let gamerecord = new {Name = gamestrings[0], Type = gamestrings[1], Difficulty = gamestrings[2]}
            where gamerecord.Type.Contains("RPG")
            select gamerecord;
```

See? now you have a strongly typed list of anonymous types that contain 3 properties:

- Name
- Type
- Difficulty

with these you can operate as if they were regular classes and access their properties, like so:

```
var gamestrings = games.Select(x => string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}", x.Name, x.Type, x.Difficulty));
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(enter + enter, gamestrings));
```

Comment: @puretppc you need to be more specific. What errors are you getting? I works just fine on my side.

Comment: @puretppc I'm using `e` as a lambda expression parameter, change that to another letter or variable name, because you already have an `e`, which is the Button event args.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. I just had to make sure things are in order.

Comment: So if I have want more fields which part of the code do I edit?

Comment: @Puretppc that's another question on it's own, don't you think? Post a new question with your current code, and your new issue and let me know.

Comment: But it's a similar question isn't it? That would be considered duplicating if it was a new question. I'm just not sure which part of the code to edit if I want to add in more fields.

Comment: @puretppc you would edit the `.Select()` which is creating an anonymous type grabbing data from each line in the game record.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues with the code and problem.

```
FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream("Games.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFileStream);
```

This will open a stream to read content from the file `Games.txt`.
You the close the stream with:

```
inputFileStream.Close();
reader.Close();
```

This should be done in reverse order. However, it is not necessary to close both the `FileStream` and the `StreamReader`. Closing the `FileStream` will also close the `StreamReader`.

A better way is to use the `using` keyword:

```
using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream("Games.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFileStream))
{
  ...
}
```

In doing so you never forget to close.

But all this code is of no use in your program. You don't use the `StreamReader` at all.
Instead you read the content from `Games.txt`:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("Games.txt");
```

Then show it:

```
MessageBox.Show(contents);
```

What you really want to do is read line by line with something like:

```
using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream("Games.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFileStream))
{
  while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
  {
    var gameName = reader.ReadLine();
    var gameType = reader.ReadLine();
    var gameDifficulty = reader.ReadLine();
    var emptyLine = reader.ReadLine();

    // Here you'll insert the logic to filter out what you want to show.
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my first post and I tried your code. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to filter out anything. instead, it's almost the same as if I'm trying to read the whole file

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
void Main()
{
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\test.txt");
var test = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
        var values = line.Split(':');
        test.Add(values[1].Trim());
    }
}

List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
for (int i = 0;i < test.Count();i = i + 3)
{
    Game game = new Game(); 
    game.Name = test[i];
    game.Type = test[i+1];
    game.Difficulty = test[i+2];

    games.Add(game);
}
var rpgGames = games.Where(w => w.Type == "RPG");
}

class Game {
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Type {get;set;}
public string Difficulty {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

1. Create a game class containing the attributes:

   ```
   class Game
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Type { get; set; }
       public string Difficulty { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Then in your method, add the following code:

   ```
   var lines =  File.ReadLines("test.txt");
   var games = new List<Game>();

   var currGame = new Game();
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
       var parts = line.Split(':');
       if (parts.Length == 1)
       {
           games.Add(currGame);
           currGame = new Game();
       }
       else if (parts[0].EndsWith("Name"))
           currGame.Name = parts[1].Trim();
       else if (parts[0].EndsWith("Type"))
           currGame.Type = parts[1].Trim();
       else
           currGame.Difficulty = parts[1].Trim();
   }

   var output = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, games.Where(x => x.Type == "RPG")
       .Select(x => string.Format("{0} [{1}] => Difficulty: {2}", x.Name, x.Type, x.Difficulty))
       .ToArray());
   Console.Write(output);
   ```